# How to change the omni-bars value without changing the website? Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect, header

I just wanted to know is there any way to change the omni-bars value without redirecting to another page using javascript? Maybe something like `omni.value = "changed.net"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.history.pushState(null, null, "/google.com");`

This will change the url without reloading the page. If you did that in the console now the url would change to `http://stackoverflow.com/google.com`. You can only change the url from the web root. So you can't make it look like a user is at `google.com` itself.

Comment: thx i heard a bit about this but I didn't know about null I knew I could change some history before.